# Non Greedy Regex Pattern Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to match  line 
/* Comment 183 EOC */

Or
/* Comment 183,200 EOC */

My Regex is like below

```
 private static final Pattern Comment = Pattern
        .compile("(/\\*(\\s*)Comment(\\s+)(((\\d*),)(\\s*))*((\\d*)(\\s*))(.*?)\\*/)");
```

I want to obtain 183 from the above input

If I try matcher.group(4) it returns nothing.

(.*?) is not acting as non greedy.

How can I change the regex to get only 183
or 183,200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
\/\*\s+Comment\s+(\d+(,\d+)*)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vR6jH4/4)

It only [captures](http://regexone.com/lesson/11) the numbers you want.

Comment: Thank you. But the input need not end with EOC it can contain any other character not numbers. For ex /*Comment 123,56,4849, 8494, gfysdft$#% */ is also valid

Comment: @user3540481 Regex updated. Now it works for /* Comment 123,1436 ,368,3648 */ as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove unnecessary capturing groups.

```
"/\\*\\s*Comment\\s+(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)\\s*(.*?)\\*/"
```

Get the number you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/1)

Comment: those number need not be one or two.. It can be any number. For ex /* Comment 123,1436 ,368,3648 */ . How your expression makes sures that?

Answer (score 0):

```
/\\*\\s*Comment\\s+([\\d, ]+)
```

You can straightaway use this grab the `group 1` .Use `find`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/2